# Python - Win32Com - Outlook - Forward today's sent items to an inbox

Tags: python-2.7, loops, outlook

I am trying to create a script to forward each day all the Outlook's sent items from 8:00 AM on to a dedicated inbox.

The message has to be saved in the sent items folder of Outlook.

At the moment I have all the emails of today but the forward part of the script does not work (I do not have any error message)

EDIT 1: Thanks to Jimmy for the restrict idea!

```
import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

outbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) 

messages = messages = outbox.Items.restrict("[SentOn] > '5/31/2017 08:00 AM'")

for message in messages:
    NewMsg = message.Forward()
    NewMsg.To = "mail@mail.com"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completed: for those interested, below you can find the solution

```
import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

outbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(5) 

messages = outbox.Items.restrict("[SentOn] > '5/30/2017 08:00 AM'")

for message in messages:
    NewMsg = message.Forward()
    NewMsg.Body = message.Body
    NewMsg.Subject = message.Subject
    NewMsg.To = "mail@mail.com"
    NewMsg.Send()
```

Comment: How could I incorporate a command: [SentOn] current date?

Answer (score 2):

There's a restrict method on the COM object you're working with that I've used before.  [check this out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx)

```
import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

outbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) 

#try the restrict method!
messages = outbox.Items.restrict("[SentOn] > '5/30/2017 12:00 AM'")

for message in messages:
    print message
```

Comment: Thank you Jimmy! Edited the first question with your answer

Comment: How could I incorporate a command: [SentOn] current date?

Comment: Hi @jimmy, how could I incorporate [SentOn]  current date?