# why message is printing but message is not forward to given mail ID using python win32com?

Tags: python, pywin32

We tried to write a code using `pywin32` to forward an e-mail to a specific sender but it is not working.

Could you help to resolve this issue.

If we print message it will print but not forward.

Here is the code:

```
import win32com.client as client
outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox=outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders('python test')
messages=inbox.items
message=messages.GetLast()

for message in messages:
   if message.SenderName =='manish.daryani@atos.net':
    message=print(message) #unable to assign print message to message how can we do instead
    NewMsg=message.Forward() # forwarding is not working 
    NewMsg.Body="Test message forwared using python"+NewMsg.Body
    NewMsg.Subject=message.Subject
    NewMsg.To=('Atos-IT-Telco-NOC@atos.net')
    NewMsg.Send()
    print('Message forwared')
```

Answer (score 0):

I see potentially several issues on your code:

1. What are you going to achieve by rewriting the `message` variable (object of Message instance) from the output of the print statement?

   - you need to remove this line
2. If you reassign the `message`variable with a new value, you cannot use it after, that's why the .Forward() does not work anymore.
3. When creating the new message body, you need to concatenate the old value from message.Body and not the new one which is empty.

The statement `print(object)` would not dump the value of your object but normally print something like:

```
<__main__.Message object at 0x102ed2f70>
```

The line saying `NewMsg=message.Forward() # forwarding is not working` would work if you remove the `message` reassignment (commented line in my code sample).

Here are some improvements but I cannot test them directly:

```
    for message in messages:
      if message.SenderName =='some-recipient@domain.net':
        # You overrides the message variable to None if you do this:
        # message = print(message) #unable to assign print message to message how can we do instead  
        # if you just need to print the message body, use:
        print(message.Body)
        newMsg = message.Forward()
        newMsg.Body = "Test message forwarded using python:" + message.Body
        newMsg.Subject = message.Subject
        newMsg.To = "new-recipient@domain.com"
        newMsg.Send()     
        print('Message successfully forwarded')
```

I took example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44281801/628006) answer which shows exactly how the for-loop must be coded for your use-case.